# Infinite cycle of bytestream

Tags: haskell

Hello I'm trying to produce infinite cycle of `ByteStream`. (not that it would be of much use, just messing around)

```
main :: IO ()
main = L.writeFile "test" $ 
  L.take 10000 $ L.cycle [0..255]
```

But because of `L.cycle [0..255]` it sais `Couldn't match expected type 'L8.ByteString' with actual type '[Integer]'`

How do I make it type match?

Comment: You can only cycle `ByteStrings`, not lists. You need to turn the list into a `ByteString` first using `L.pack :: [Word8] -> L.ByteString`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

main :: IO ()
main = L.writeFile "test" $ 
  L.take 10000 $ L.cycle (L.pack [0..255])
```

`cycle` has a type of `ByteString -> ByteString` and you are supplying it a list of integers and that's why you get a compile error. You can use the [pack](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy.html#v:pack) function to convert a list of `Word8` to `ByteString`.